# If a firm sponsors your GDL and LPC, and you then leave before doing the training contract, do you have to pay them back? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-education

More or less all in the title. Presumably this might vary a bit between firms but I'm looking for an overview of what is the case in (a) magic circle firms and (b) other UK firms that offer sponsorship.

Comment: I assume by GDL and LPC  you mean the Graduate Diploma in Law and Legal Practice Course?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean

Comment: This depends entirely on what is in the contract. There is no general answer beyond that; any answer for a specific contract is to give legal advice to the person involved, and that's not accepted here.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add the details you have in mind regarding the terms & conditions of sponsorship. Be sure to explain also what "magic circle" means in this context.